# How to take value of JTextfield declared in main function from outside of main function?

Tags: java, swing

I've declared text field as:

```
public class ContactInformation implements ActionListener {
private JTextField finame;
private JTextField laname;
private JTextField dist;
private JTextField cty;

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
JTextField fname = new JTextField(20);
JTextField lname = new JTextField(20);
JTextField district = new JTextField(20);
JTextField city = new JTextField(20);
}

public void insertUser(){
 try {
    contains = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contact_info","root","");
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        stmt = contains.prepareStatement(insertUser);
        stmt.setString(1,a);
        stmt.setString(2,b);
        int rowinserted = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rowinserted>0){
            System.out.println("Inserted successfully!!!");
        }
  } 
}
```

So, my program structure is like above. In this code I have to take value from text box into `stmt.setString(1,a);` [in the field a there should be value of text field].

How I get value from text box to `a`?

Comment: Use the method `getText()`. For example `fname.getText()`

Comment: Strategies to solve: 1) Don't use a non-blocking top level contain such as a `JFrame` to collect the information! Instead get the information from `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` ***or*** 2) Move the code satements after the information is input, into the action performed method of the action listener attached to the input component. When the user presses 'enter', that code will be executed.

Comment: General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: BTW - this code is shadowing variables: Change `JTextField fname = new JTextField(20);` to just `fname = new JTextField(20);` (same for the others) then move it into a constructor for `ContactInformation`. Call that constructor from the `main(String[])` method.

Comment: The more I look at that code, the more problems I see. Really too broad to go into. Toss it out and return to command line apps. until you can spot at least 6 errors in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the value of your JTextField "finame" as a, you must write:

```
stmt.setString(1, finame.getText());
```

Also your creating new JTextFields in your main, not the ones you declared in your class! You must create an constructor and create them in it:
Correct:

```
public static void ContactInformation(String [] args) throws Exception{
    finame = new JTextField(20);
    laname = new JTextField(20);
    dist = new JTextField(20);
    cty = new JTextField(20);
}
```

Notice the missing "JTextField" and the corrected names.

In your main-Method you have to call that constructor:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    ContactInformation contactInformation = new ContactInformation();
    //TODO work with contactInformation
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firmly coming to the answer you require. If you want the value at "a"
 just use the code `fnmae.getText()` and you will get value of fname textfield.